# How to consolidate action buttons for individual objects into a single selectInput() in R shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny-reactivity, observers, rhandsontable

The code posted below allows the user via clicks of action buttons to add/delete individual rhandsontable tables for data input. For deletion each table has its own action button underneath. Any ideas how to consolidate those delete action buttons into a single `selectInput()` where all tables are listed for deletion? I've tried un-nesting the deletion function `observeEvent(input[[btnID]]...)` which triggers a `removeUI()`, for quite a while now, but I have completely hit a brick wall.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

data1 <- data.frame(row.names = c("A","B","C","Sum"),"Tbl 1"=c(1,1,0,2),check.names=FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(br(),
  actionButton("addTbl","Add table"),br(),br(),
  tags$div(id="placeholder",tags$div(rHandsontableOutput("hottable1")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  uiTbl <- reactiveValues(div_01_tbl = data1) 
  rv <- reactiveValues()                
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable1, {uiTbl$div_01_tbl <- hot_to_r(input$hottable1)})
  
  output$hottable1 <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(uiTbl$div_01_tbl, useTypes = TRUE)})
  
  observeEvent(input$addTbl, {
    divID <- paste0("div_", if(input$addTbl+1 < 10){"0"},input$addTbl+1)
    dtID <- paste0(divID, "_DT")
    btnID <- paste0(divID, "_rmv")
    uiTbl[[paste0(divID,"_tbl")]] <- data1 
    
    insertUI(selector = "#placeholder",
      ui = tags$div(id = divID,
        rHandsontableOutput(dtID), 
        actionButton(btnID, "Delete", class = "pull-left btn btn-danger"),
      )
    )
    
    output[[dtID]] <- renderRHandsontable({
      req(uiTbl[[paste0(divID,"_tbl")]])
      rhandsontable(uiTbl[[paste0(divID,"_tbl")]], useTypes = TRUE)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input[[dtID]], {uiTbl[[paste0(divID,"_tbl")]] <- hot_to_r(input[[dtID]])})
    
    observeEvent(input[[btnID]],{
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#", divID))
      rv[[divID]] <- NULL
      uiTbl[[paste0(divID,"_tbl")]] <- NULL
    },
    ignoreInit = TRUE,
    once = TRUE)
  })
  
  observe({
    tables_list <- reactiveValuesToList(uiTbl)
    tables_list <- tables_list[order(names(tables_list))]
    table_lengths <- lengths(tables_list)
    cumsum_table_lengths <- cumsum(table_lengths)[table_lengths != 0L]
    for(i in seq_along(cumsum_table_lengths)){
      names(uiTbl[[names(cumsum_table_lengths[i])]]) <- paste("Col", cumsum_table_lengths[i])
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect the user's deletion choices as a reactive value in the **server part**:

```
    deletable_tables <- reactiveVal()
```

... add a select input to your **UI** (I chose a selectize input)

```
    selectizeInput('deletionSelector', 'delete tables:',
                   choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE,
                   options = list(placeholder = 'choose table(s)')
                   )
```

and update this value in your event observer for `input$addTbl`:

```
    observeEvent(input$addTbl, {
    ## ...
        deletable_tables(c(deletable_tables(),  dtID))

        updateSelectizeInput(inputId = 'deletionSelector', 
                             session = session, 
                             choices = deletable_tables()
                             )
    ## ...
    }
```

(note that a `reactiveVal` is set with an argument rather than via assignment operator: `my_reactive_val(x)` instead of `my_reactive_val <- x`)

**edit**
Please see working version below. I added a "Delete" button: when triggering delete on selection change, tables would be removed until none are left.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

data1 <- data.frame(row.names = c("A","B","C","Sum"),"Tbl 1"=c(1,1,0,2),check.names=FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectizeInput('deletionSelector', 'delete tables:',
                   choices = NULL, multiple = FALSE,
                   options = list(placeholder = 'choose table(s)')
                   ),
    p(actionButton('deleteTbl', 'delete selection')),
    p(actionButton("addTbl","Add table")),
    tags$div(id="placeholder",tags$div(rHandsontableOutput("hottable1"))),
    )


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    ## store the tables in a list "data" within the
    ## reactive list "ui_tables":
    ui_tables <- reactiveValues(data = list()) 
    delete_ID <- reactiveVal()
    
    ## present initial table on initialisation
    observe({
        ui_tables$data$div_01_tbl <- rhandsontable(data1, useTypes = TRUE)
        output$hottable1 <- renderRHandsontable(ui_tables$data$div_01_tbl)
    }) |> bindEvent('input$addTbl')    

    observeEvent(input$addTbl, {
        divID <- sprintf('div_%02.f', input$addTbl + 1)
        dtID <- paste0(divID, '_tbl')
        ui_tables$data[[dtID]] <- rhandsontable(data1, useTypes = TRUE)
        
        insertUI(selector = "#placeholder",
                 ui = tags$div(id = divID,
                               h4(dtID),
                               rHandsontableOutput(outputId = dtID))
                 )

        output[[dtID]] <- renderRHandsontable({ui_tables$data[[dtID]]})
        
        updateSelectizeInput(
            inputId = 'deletionSelector', 
            session = session, 
            choices = c(dtID, names(ui_tables$data))
        )
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE, ignoreNULL = TRUE)


    observe({        
        delete_ID(input$deletionSelector)
        div_id  = gsub('(div_.*?)_.*$', '\\1', delete_ID())
        removeUI(selector = paste0('#', div_id))
        ui_tables$data[[delete_ID()]] <- NULL
        updateSelectizeInput(inputId = 'deletionSelector', session = session, 
                             choices = names(ui_tables$data)
                             )

    }) |>  bindEvent(input$deleteTbl)

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi I_O, I adopted your recommendations but still trying to work out kinks. Please see revised code. I now have to click "Add tables" action button twice in order to add the first table, and I can only delete a table one time and then the deletion function no longer works. This may be due to deletions causing `uiTbl` names to no longer track with divID. I can revise the code to include a simple counter for number of deletions, let me know if I should revise the code with this. Also, only a single table should be deletable with a click so I made that change too in `selectizeInput`.

Comment: Your explanations and changes are clear. This is my first time seeing `bindEvent` and it's very useful: "Modify an object to respond to "event-like" reactive inputs, values, and expressions. `bindEvent()` can be used with reactive expressions, render functions, and observers. The resulting object takes a reactive dependency on the ... arguments, and not on the original object's code. This can, for example, be used to make an observer execute only when a button is pressed."

Comment: Adding the delete button was a very good idea, to slow the user down before over-deleting